# Problemas com Session em aplicação MVC usando ActionFilters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-pattern

Tenho um problema em minha aplicação `ASP.Net MVC`, sobre autenticação. Vamos por passos:

1) Tenho minha tela de login `/Login/Index` simplesmente o usuário loga, se encontrado no banco `MySQL`, e inicia a sessão e redireciona para  `/Dashboard/Index`.  Este é o código de verificação de usuário e se correto inicia a sessão: 
    [Obs:] Eu uso objeto `SessionManager` Genérico e um `ISessionOperation` com com métodos que `Start`, `Finish`, `IsActive`, `GetSessionId`, `GetUsuario`.
    Segue o código abaixo da `Action Login HttpPost`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Logar(UsuarioDto Model, string Remind)
{
    try
    {
        var UsuarioLogado = UsuarioDomain.Authentication(Model);

        if (UsuarioLogado != null)
        {
            //--> Acesso
            var AcessoDomain = new SmartAdmin.Domain.Acesso();
            AcessoDomain.Save(GetUserInformation(String.Empty));

            //--> Menus & Submenus
            var CollectionMenuMain = new List<MenuModelView>();                    
            foreach (var MenuMain in UsuarioDomain.GetAllowedMenus(UsuarioLogado.ID)) //--> Para cada menu pai pega os filhos e adiciona no modelo de visão
            {
               var CollectionSubMenus = UsuarioDomain.GetSubMenuFromMenu(MenuMain.ID);
               var CurrentMenuMain = new MenuModelView() { Menu = MenuMain, CollectionSubMenu = CollectionSubMenus }; 
               CollectionMenuMain.Add(CurrentMenuMain);
            }

            //--> Session
            var Session = new SessionManager();
            Session.Start(new UsuarioModelView() { Usuario = UsuarioLogado, CollectionMenusAndSubMenus = CollectionMenuMain });

            return (RedirectToAction("Index", "Menu"));
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["Mensagem"] = "Usuário inexistente ou não esta ativo no sistema, contate o Administrador!";
            return (RedirectToAction("Index", "Login"));
        }  
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(Ex.Message);
    }
}
```

2) A segunda questão é que trato todas as `Actions` da minha aplicação com `ActionFilter` ou seja criei um `ActionFilter` que verifica se a sessão está ativa. Se não estiver redireciono para `/Login/Index`. Se estiver ativa procede o acesso a `Action` chamada, segue o exemplo de minha `ActionFilter` que uso:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var Session = new SessionManager();

    if (Session.IsActive() == false)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
        {
            controller = "Login",
            action = "Index"
        }));
 }
```

Faço uso dela desta forma em minhas `Actions` dentro da maioria dos `controllers` da minha aplição, uma coisa comum de se usar ok.

```
[AuthorizedUser]
public ActionResult Cedente()
{
    var CedenteDomain = new Cedente();
    var Model = CedenteDomain.GetItem(_ => _.ID == 1);

    ViewBag.Mensagem = (TempData["Mensagem"] as String);
    return View((Model==null)?new CedenteDto(): Model);
}
```

3) Vamos ao problema!, Seguinte, isso em desenvolvimento, local em meu `Visual Studio 2012`, e até o `IIS7` local configurado
   está funcionando corretamente parametrizei no `webconfig` `sessionTimeOut` para 60 também. Mas o problema maior é que 
   quando compilo e coloco no meu domínio de hospedagem e tento logar ele loga devidamente mas quando clico em links internos
   dentro da minha aplicação ele redireciona para a pagina de /Login/Index não sei por que e recentemente cliquei com o botão 
   direito do mouse num link interno e mandei abrir em nova aba e ele carregou corretamente, a questão é, quando logo e clico
   em qualquer menu ex:

Financeiro

- 1 - Boletos 2 - Cedente 3 - Caixa

Ele redireciona para Login/Index, mas quando mando abrir em nova aba pelo Chrome por exemplo ele carrega corretamente, as vezes ele redireciona também para `Login/Index`.

Isso tudo não acontece localmente.

4)  Andei buscando pela internet e vi que usar `Session` é muito ruim tals em fim não vou entrar em detalhes uma alternativa seria usar Cache mas a pergunta objetiva seria como solucionar isso.Detalhe todas as minhas URL de menu estao configuradas `@Url.Action('~/Controller/Action')` creio que esteja devidamente correto.

Comment: Por que não usa o provider padrão do asp.net mvc ? identity

Answer (score 2):

Rodrigo, acredito que o problema está na forma como o seu serviço de hospedagem faz o balanceamento das requisições, possivelmente você está sendo levado a servidores diferentes a cada requisição.

Como você deve está usando um `In-process Session State`, então é importante que o usuário sempre acesse o mesmo servidor onde ele fez o primeiro acesso.

Talvez uma solução imediada para o seu problema, seria usar um `Out-of-Proc State Server`, seja um `Session State Service` ou um `SQL Session State`.

Caso decida utilizar o `SQL Server` como `Session State`, você pode seguir este guia na [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/317604). No caso do MySQL, você vai precisar escrever o seu proprio Provider, segue um exemplo encontrado no [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/633199/Using-MySQL-Session-State-Provider-for-ASP-NET)

Comment: Entendi, sim, é estranho se a cada requisição o balanceamento acessar diversos servidores mesmo, ai complica usar session. não tinha pensado neste fato, vou tentar implementar a solução do provider para MySQL, ai posto aqui se deu certo ou não. valeu!!!

Comment: Ola eu fiz um objeto Session (implementando Session Provider) mas estou tendo alguns problemas para finalizar alguns métodos tem algum exemplo ?